# Unwanted Character When Looping Word Tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a simple table on a Word document.
When I run the code to loop thru the rows in the table and print the contents of the first column out to the Immediate Window you get a dot below each word.
I tried stripping this dot out using code but because the dot is below the characters on each line I don’t seem to be able to get this to work.

I need to get rid of this dot because what I eventually want to do is compare the contents of each cell to a search string and if they match update another field.

If you have a table on a Word document even without anything entered in the cells and click the Show/Hide Character Marks button – Home toolbar Paragraph section you can see what I believe to be the cause.

```
Dim tbl As Table, r As Long
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Debug.Print tbl.Cell(r, 1).Range.Text

Next r
```

Input

[image]

This is the output I get

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment on your previous question, you need to remove the last two characters (the "end of cell marker", chr(13) + chr(7)  )

```
txt = tbl.Cell(r, 1).Range.Text
Debug.Print Left(txt, Len(txt)-2)
```

Comment: Tim Williams - thanks, i did not read you reply correctly and i was only removing 1 character - ooops, curious to know how you knew there was two characters to remove though??

Comment: I think there are some things in Word you just "have to know" - it's not obvious, and the term "end of cell marker" is not anything you'd know to Google for, but once you've found it you tend not to forget.